# Replacement of JRequest::getVar('return', '', 'method', 'base64')

Tags: joomla-3.x

I'am updating code for Joomla! 3.5/3.6. I want to replace the following JRequest call by JInput, but i don't know the method i should use for that :

```
$return = base64_decode(JRequest::getVar('return', '', 'method', 'base64'));
```

The following is the correct replacement :

```
$return = $app->input->getbase64('return');
```

?

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

$return = base64_decode($input->get('return', '', 'BASE64'));
```